# WSS -filtering a custom web part

Tags: sharepoint

I have a list and I am using a web user control and the Smart Part web part to show a list item. (The Smart Part web part lets us use web user controls as "web parts".)

My list contains many items, but I need to show only one. So I am planning to add a dropdownlist to filter by ID and show that item only, and then persist that selection in an XML file/ database.

Would you recommend that approach? I am on WSS -I think I don't have MOSS' filter web parts available.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who needs to be able to change the item that is shown ?

If it's the end-user and you really want to show a dropdown inside the webpart, there's always the option to store the selected ID in the property bag of the SPWeb containing your webpart. That way you don't need a separate database or xml file.

If only an admin needs to be able to change this, it's even easier. You could then create a webpart property in which you can enter the ID.